# Sumar horas de fecha de entrada y salida

Tags: mysql, mysqli

[image: Ver imagen]Hola, no consigo sumar las horas de entrada y salida por días, en todos los días me suma el total de entrada y salida y no el total de entrada y salida por días, del primer día deberían salir 6 horas y del segundo día deberían salir 1 hora y me suma el total en los dos días, 7 horas.

```
SELECT usuarios.nombre, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, "%Y-%m-%d") as fecha1, (SELECT sum(DATE_FORMAT(fecha, "%H:%i")) from horas where tipo='salida' group by id_usuarios) - 
(SELECT sum(DATE_FORMAT(fecha, "%H:%i")) from horas where tipo='entrada' group by id_usuarios) AS horas1 From horas, usuarios group by fecha1
```

Comment: Por que no agrupas por `tipo`?

Comment: Puedes por favor leer [ask] y generar un ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable donde muestres en código la estructura de las tablas involucradas así como datos de ejemplo para poderte responder?

Comment: he agrupado por tipo y tampoco me desglosa las horas, saludos

Comment: Por favor, modifica tu pregunta para incluir el dataset que puedes obtener con phpMyAdmin/Exportar, así podremos probar tu consulta y ver en qué falla